# Disable suggestions as you type on Numbers

Tags: macos, numbers

It seems that Numbers give a suggestion based on what is already in the sheet. Like in the image.

How to disable this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Preferences in Numbers,

and disable the

> Show suggestions when EDITING..

.

it is enabled by default.

[image]